# ASP.NET Web API hosted in IIS 10.0 with windows authentication and custom responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication, iis-10, .net-7.0

I'm hosting an ASP.NET Core 7 Web API using Minimal API in IIS 10.0. I have Windows authentication and anonymous authentication enabled in `launchsettings.json` since I want some routes to be allowed for anonymous access.

The problem is that I want to use a custom DTO for all 400-599 error responses but when I try to access for example a route requiring Windows authentication, the request doesn't even reach my Web API code. IIS automatically responds with a 401 without a body.

I've tried using both

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseExceptionHandler();
```

but the request doesn't reach any of them.

How can I make IIS not interrupt the request and let my code generate the response?

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: "I have Windows authentication and anonymous authentication enabled in launchsettings.json since I want some routes to be allowed for anonymous access" is impossible to achieve. When anonymous authentication is on, everything is anonymous. You'd better split the code into separate projects for different authentication methods.

Comment: Actually it's not impossible as I'm doing it right now in my project... I don't know why you made this comment since this wasn't even a question I had.

Comment: You will find IIS was designed with a different philosophy that works better with what I suggested. The more you want to show your capabilities, the more extra tuning you need to do (like disable IIS Windows authentication but emulate it on ASP.NET Core side).

Comment: A 401 is the normal first response for Windows Authentication, with an "Authentication" header set to "Negotiate". Then it's up to the browser to send credentials. If it's prompting you for credentials, put in your credentials and see if it works. If it does, that's good. For the browser to automatically send credentials, the web site's domain needs to be in the Trusted Sites or Intranet Sites in the Windows Internet Options (for Chrome and Edge anyway - Firefox has its own settings)